# Equal sign in bad place causes unknown token exception

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I'm upgrading a react babel 5 project to babel 6.  The code is from [pluralsight](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/react-styling-components/table-of-contents) on [github](https://github.com/jaketrent/react-drift).  The error occurs on [app.js](https://github.com/jaketrent/react-drift/blob/master/src/app.js#L13).  I assume there is a plugin that needs an upgrade that allows this syntax to work:

```
export default class DriftApp extends React.Component {
  state = {//builder is not happy with this equals sign, unexpected token
    showIndex: 0,
    numSlides: 5
  }
```

Which plugin does this?

Here's my package.json:

```
 "homepage": "https://github.com/jaketrent/react-drift#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autobind-decorator": "^1.3.3",
    "babel-core": "^6.5.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.4",
    "radium": "^0.16.6",
    "react": "^0.14.2",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^2.0.0-alpha-4",
    "react-tools": "^0.10.0",
    "react-transform": "0.0.3",
    "react-transform-catch-errors": "^1.0.0",
    "react-transform-hmr": "^1.0.1",
    "redbox-react": "^1.1.1",
    "webpack": "^1.12.2",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.2.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.4.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, but aren't you already in a dictionnary, shoudn't it be state : { ... } ?

Comment: @phenxd - I tried changing the problem character from `=` to `:`.  Just changed the error: `A semicolon is required after a class property`.  I am confident the code on github is in working condition.  This is example code written for pluralsight.  It should have a lot of traffic/test users.  Click the link to [app.js](https://github.com/jaketrent/react-drift/blob/master/src/app.js#L13) for the full code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using property initializers syntax in your code, which is an experimental feature (proposal). You can transpile this to ES5 by installing the babel-plugin-transform-class-properties module

```
npm install babel-plugin-transform-class-properties  --save-dev
```

Add the following line to your .babelrc file:

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]
}
```

ref https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/

Answer (score 2):

Add the `babel-preset-stage-0` npm module and add `stage-0` to your babel presets.

If you want an example babel 6 configuration that works well with React, look at the `package.json` and `.babelrc` from the [react-redux-starter-kit](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit).

Comment: Struggling with ENOENT error installing the preset.  This answer looks promising.  Windoze...