# Babel / Webpack settings for react-sketchapp project with ES2015 & ES.next

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, ecmascript-next

I am trying integrate the into a react-sketchapp app but am running into some compilation errors.

My project is based on [this example](https://github.com/airbnb/react-sketchapp/tree/master/examples/basic-setup), and I have posted the [**entire repo on github**](https://github.com/pcooney10/rn-calendar).

**Problem:**

I am getting a build error from the `react-native-calendars` npm package that is using this ES6+ syntax:

```
static propTypes = {
  theme: PropTypes.object,
  markedDates: PropTypes.object,
  style: ViewPropTypes.style,
...
};
```

The app breaks at the "equals sign" after `static propTypes`, and the error message looks like this:

```
// Unexpected token (18:19)
// You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
class Calendar extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
   // Specify theme properties to override specific styles for calendar 
   parts. Default = {}
   theme: PropTypes.object,
// @ ./node_modules/react-native-calendars/src/index.js 1:0-49
```

**Attempted Solution:**

I can add a `.babelrc` or `webpack.config.js` file to the project, so I am trying the following .babelrc presets:

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "stage-0"]
}
```

I also tried these babel presets:

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "stage-0", "es2015"],
  "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread", "transform-class-properties"]
}
```

and a few more variations using `"react-native"` and `"stage-2"`, but am still getting the same error . Any help would be greatly appreciated !

**Edit:**

I updated the example to exclude an earlier issue I was having (jsx wasn't recognized without the "react" preset), and posted the entire repo [on github](https://github.com/pcooney10/rn-calendar).

Comment: you need the "react" bable preset. otherwise babel won't understand the JSX syntax.

Comment: @ThomasDevries ah ok thank you. It's giving me the error on `static propTypes= { theme: PropTypes.object }` again.

Comment: I also tried using the "react-native" babel preset (the npm module is a react-native module), but still no luck. Do certain presets overwrite each other, like if I were to do something like this: `"presets": ["stage-0", "es2015", "react", "react-native"]`? @ThomasDevries

Comment: Change the preset order to: react -> es2015 -> stage-0

Comment: No luck there either, but thank you for the response @HugodoCarmo. I have posted a copy of the repo here: https://github.com/pcooney10/rn-calendar

Comment: That syntax is a **proposal**, not part of ES7 (ES2015).

Comment: `stage-0` should work btw, assuming this is inside a class. Would be helpful to provide more context of the code. Possible duplicate of [Equal sign in bad place causes unknown token exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35345000/218196)

Comment: Ok thank you for the clarification & advice. Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/pcooney10/e2e699549e47284f3eae8aca390c2148) of the offending code. The compiler doesn't like the `=` sign on line 18 @FelixKing

Comment: Does this have something to do with the file being in `node_modules`? Does `.babelrc` ignore files in here?

Comment: I think that depends on your webpack config. skpm might have configured it in such a way that it won't transform JS files in `node_modules`.

Comment: @pingo skpm is not using babel `strace node_modules/.bin/skpm build 2>&1 | grep babel`. Using `babel-cli` it was possible to verify that it is working (`node_modules/.bin/babel -f .babelrc ./node_modules/react-native-calendars/src/agenda/index.js`) using the following preset order `["react", "es2015", "stage-0"]`

Comment: Ok thank you again for the help on this @FelixKling. I opened an [issue](https://github.com/skpm/skpm/issues/53) to see if they can provide any color.

Comment: Thank you @HugodoCarmo !!!!!!

Comment: So.. the million dollar question... how do I get my app to work? I think a `webpack.config.js` should do the trick (`skpm` seems to use it), but I am not sure I am doing it correctly. Here is my attempt: https://gist.github.com/pcooney10/7ba80782c92fbb1e230cbecb12ddcdca @HugodoCarmo

Comment: Check my [webpack.config](https://gist.github.com/spelcaster/cb9931918ed2e52a43e276c952c8604e), It read my app entry and concatenate everything in a single file, perhaps you can use this file in skpm...